# Error with library Qt5Network

Tags: c++, qt, linker, libraries, archlinux

My laptop is running arch, and I'm not too familiar with handling libraries yet. I installed some new libraries, mainly qt libraries and I must have broken something. I can't run okular anymore, giving me same error message as `ldd /usr/lib/libQt5Network.so` does. Also I can't link some object files anymore due to this problem.

```
ldd /usr/lib/libQt5Network.so
/usr/lib/libQt5Network.so: /usr/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0: version `OPENSSL_1.0.1' not found (required by /usr/lib/libQt5Network.so)
/usr/lib/libQt5Network.so: /usr/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0: version `OPENSSL_1.0.2' not found (required by /usr/lib/libQt5Network.so)
/usr/lib/libQt5Network.so: /usr/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0: version `OPENSSL_1.0.0' not found (required by /usr/lib/libQt5Network.so)
/usr/lib/libQt5Network.so: /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: version `OPENSSL_1.0.2' not found (required by /usr/lib/libQt5Network.so)
/usr/lib/libQt5Network.so: /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: version `OPENSSL_1.0.0' not found (required by /usr/lib/libQt5Network.so)
```

What exacty means that error message? And how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to install openssl

```
sudo apt-get install openssl
```